# LightSwitch lost connection to database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have designed a silverlight application using Visual Studio Lightswitch. I added a screen that shows the  details screen. Looked at the code behind and tried to add.

```
partial void Application_initialize()
        {
            this.Details.ClientTimeout = 1000;
        }
```

An error came out that it does not contain a definition for ClientTimeout and no extension method.
My intention is to maintain a  connection to my database and display the data in a details screen always.

How can maintain the connection even when idle?

Also the details was showing only 52 records instead of more 1000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that code in the Application.cs file, not in a screen's code.

The easiest way to get there is:

- right-click on the LightSwitch project in *Solution Explorer*
- select *View Application Code (Client)*

You sure it wasn't showing 45 records? By default, the query source for a grid has paging set to *on*, & the number of items set to *45 per page*. If you look down at the bottom of the screen, there should be a page control, that allows you to move from page to page.

To set paging *off*, or to change the *number of items per page*, in the top left of the screen designer, click on the screen query, then over on the right-hand side of the designer you'll see some checkboxes. One of them is *Support Paging*. If that box is ticked, there'll be a textbox underneath it (which disappears if you uncheck the box), with the number of items per page.

[image: Paging Options]

Comment: I am looking into that. Thanks Yann. Will get back to you asap.

Comment: An error occured saying A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

Comment: I am getting Red X now. I sorted that issue. I have removed the code above.